# SignalR with CORS on Azure not working

Tags: azure, signalr, cors

I'm having trouble getting Signalr to support CORS on Azure.  I've created the MSDN  [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) sample chat program, deployed it to Azure and made sure it worked ok.  Then I followed the instructions for how to enable CORS in the [SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client), i.e, I changed Startup.cs to use Microsoft.Owin.Cors and set

```
map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
```

and tried it with IE11 on Win8.

Signalr/IE is sending a CORS preflight request like this:

```
Request OPTIONS /signalr/signalr/negotiate?connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22ommhub%22%7D%5D&clientProtocol=1.3&_=1398784789992 HTTP/1.1
Accept  */*
Origin  https://my.devserver.com
Access-Control-Request-Method   GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers  content-type, accept, x-requested-with
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; LCJB; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Host    mytestsite.azurewebsites.net
Content-Length  0
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

and Azure is returning something that almost looks right:

```
Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Allow   OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
Content-Length  0
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Public  OPTIONS, TRACE, GET, HEAD, POST
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Set-Cookie  ARRAffinity=6115ee2c8e2594676e68d4f0ee51035a2;Path=/;Domain=mytestsite.azurewebsites.net
Date    Tue, 29 Apr 2014 15:23:43 GMT
```

but the browser never sends anything after this (it should be requesting a connection).  I suspect it might be because the preflight response does not include the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

There's a lot of conflicting information on the web about this.  Has anyone successfully gotten a SignalR hub working with CORS on Azure?  If you're out there, please tell us how you did it.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time to debug the Signalr code but I figured out a workaround.

I proxy the Signalr request through an URL in the same domain that another service (that handles CORS correctly) is being loaded from.  Once the OPTIONS preflight request is handled by the other service, IE allows all further requests to happen without preflight.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following does work:

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{
    map.UseCors(_corsOptions.Value);
    //map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll); // also ok but perhaps a little bit too open
    var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
    {
        EnableDetailedErrors = false
    };

    map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
});
```

with _corsOptions.Value like this:

```
private static Lazy<CorsOptions> _corsOptions = new Lazy<CorsOptions>(() =>
{
    return new CorsOptions
    {
        PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
        {
            PolicyResolver = context =>
            {
                var policy = new CorsPolicy();
                policy.Origins.Add("http...");
                policy.AllowAnyMethod = true;
                policy.AllowAnyHeader = true;
                policy.SupportsCredentials = true;
                return Task.FromResult(policy);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

But unfortunately this is more or less the code from the sample you mentioned that is not working for you.

What about your web.config? Is it clean or is there CORS stuff like

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

I don't remember precisely if it should be there or not. So if it is not working and it is there, remove it otherwise you could try to add it...

Answer (score 0):

If it can help, on my side, I used :

- `map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll)`;
- no customHeaders in `web.config`
- took off * from my Azure CORS Allowed-Origin (yep, I had to take it off to stop getting the cross domain error from my local js client)

Answer (score 0):

To get signalr working when **deployed to azure**, I had to use:

1. no customHeaders in web.config
2. use cors with corsoptions
3. appBuilder.SetDataProtectionProvider

About 2: inside startup configure:

```
 appBuilder.Map("/signalr", map =>
 {
    var corsOptions = new Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions
    {
       PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
       {
          PolicyResolver = context => ResolvePolicy()
       }
   };
   map.UseCors(corsOptions);
 }
```

with ResolvePolicy():

```
private Task<System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy> ResolvePolicy() {

        var corsPolicy = new System.Web.Cors.CorsPolicy()
        {
            AllowAnyMethod = true,
            AllowAnyHeader = true,
            SupportsCredentials = true
        };

        corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://ng2a-hneu-web-ui.azurewebsites.net");
        corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://localhost:3000");

        return Task.FromResult(corsPolicy);
    }
```

About 3: inside startup.cs, Configure()

```
appBuilder.SetDataProtectionProvider(new MachineKeyProtectionProvider());
```

Here is the link to [gist](https://gist.github.com/HNeukermans/d2252e9107ded8d0fb867aef300222f4).

I found the solution on the **official signalr github**. 
Follow this link : [ASP.NET 5 app in Azure doesn't work with SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3659).

This issue only occurs when deploying to Azure. In dev mode, using ISS express everything seemed to be working fine.

Also a very important thing when adding allowed origins is NOT to postfix them with a **slash**.

```
corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://xxxx**/**"); //incorrect
corsPolicy.Origins.Add("http://xxx); //correct
```